# Black screen after installing nvidia graphics driver

Tags: black-screen-of-death

> CPU: Intel g4400
>   Motherboard: GIGABYTE ga-h110m-ds2v
>   Power supply: FSP hyper k 500w 80+
>   Monitor: AOC IF23 (only DVI and D-SUB)

I bought gtx 750ti recently and after I installed nvidia graphics driver, my monitor began to blink and now it is black.
It looks like some people experienced the same issue but unlike solved cases, I can’t approach to safe mode and uninstall nvidia graphics driver visually.

What I found is that even if my monitor shows nothing, my keyboard and Windows 10 are working fine.

For example, I can type my password in Windows 10 login screen. And I can shutdown my computer through Windows command prompt by pressing Windows logo key on my keyboard, typing ‘`prompt`’, pressing Enter key, typing ‘`shutdown /s`’ and pressing Enter key while I can’t see anything.
It looks crazy but it is working in this way.

I sort of confirmed this in this way. When my monitor goes power save mode - about 10 minutes interval - my monitor shows orange light. And when I click my mouse, my monitor shows blue light again and my monitor shows Windows screen for about a second before goes black again. And during that time, I can see icons on my Windows screen and the Windows command prompt window if I used the above method - press Windows logo key, type ‘`prompt`’, and press Enter key - and I didn’t type ‘`shutdown /s`’.

Is there a way that I can uninstall nvidia graphics driver by using only keyboard? I want to try to uninstall nvidia graphics card by using a second when I can see Windows screen. But waiting 10 minutes and clicking right options during a second are not easy tasks I think.

Here is what I did:

1. changing the dedicated graphics card to the integrated graphics card
2. replacing the power supply
3. replacing the DVI to DVI cable
4. getting new gtx 750ti from the seller

Additional infos

I can’t see cursor. My monitor shows blue light as it was normal.

And Even if I use del key when the motherboard manufacturer’s logo is visible, I can’t see BIOS screen. But I can still press F10(save & exit), left arrow key to select ‘yes’, and Enter key without seeing anything and my computer will restart.
If I press the power button, I can see gigabyte logo and Windows logo but I can’t see anything after that.

And I removed gtx 750ti and am using the integrated graphics card(g4400).

Comment: Is your Nvidia card from a reputable/trustworthy seller? If not then chances are it's a "fake", ie, an older Nvidia chipset, typically a GT400 series tweaked to show up as GTX750ti. Those typically work (sort of) in Windows but problems start as soon as the card can't cope with the drivers' demands that are fit for the real GTX750ti.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think it’s possible cause I bought the secondhand graphics card from the seller. But if it is and I remove 750ti and connect to the integrated GPU, shouldn’t Monitor show Windows screen again? And I couldn’t use the replaced 750ti much because of black screen.

Comment: And I am an atheist.

Comment: If everything else is fine then yes, changing back to the integrated graphics should give you a normal video output.

Comment: Strange. The results are same whether I use the dedicated or integrated graphics cards. I managed to approach to Windows safe mode but my monitor showed nothing.

Comment: I will try to connect my dedicated graphics card to a TV with HDMI to HDMI cable. And I will try to use HDMI to DVI cable, too. I hope the HDMI ports work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm editing my answer because I think that is correct and will be more friendly.

First, Open CMD as Administrator, and watch your **Drivers List** by enter command:

```
pnputil -e
```

If you can't scroll without your mouse, you may want to **export the list to TXT file**, use that:

```
pnputil -e > C:\export.txt
```

(That is example to path)
Now when you know what 'inf' is associated to Graphic card, **Remove the driver** by using next command:

```
pnputil -d Oem_num.inf
```

*'Oem_num.inf' - is example to the 'inf' file that associated with the driver you want to remove.*

There is **more examples** about using pnputil:

```
pnputil /delete-driver oem0.inf         <- Delete driver package
pnputil /delete-driver oem1.inf /force  <- Force delete driver package
```

Those provide by **help menu**:

```
pnputil /?
```

Comment: After typing first two codes, I can see my driver name. And if I type the third code with my driver name, I can uninstall the driver. Am I following?

Comment: @Kim I found friendly code, that I think will be better. After use that, i'm assure you solve the problem quickly. By the way, you can use "Team viewer" with quick-view and take care your PC with mouse remotely.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Your edited answer is straightforward. If I can see the screen for more than a second, I can record a clear video with my phone and read the list of my drivers well. I can’t, but I want to try. And my mouse is working, too.

Comment: Actually, I was and am trying to use ‘reset this pc’ to clean Windows. So unfortunately I think I will see the result of this last resort first. Like I wrote, with black screen even using one method takes a lot of time. Given that seeing the result of your answer takes less time, it is unfortunate.

Comment: ‘Reset this pc’ didn’t work. I guess it means the driver was not guilty. But when I tried to use an LED TV, both integrated and dedicated graphics worked. I used the DVI-D(PC) to HDMI(TV) cable. I think my monitor had a problem but still don’t know what exactly was the problem. I will buy a new monitor with an HDMI port.